# How to get the exact value from sql query in pymysql?

Tags: python-3.5, pymysql

I cannot get exact value from my query. Here is function that I wrote:

```
def test():
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `neg_score` FROM `allwords` WHERE `synset_terms_en`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ("unable",))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Here is the result that I get:

```
{'neg_score': 0.75}
```

What I want to see is that:

```
0.75
```

After I get what I expect, then I want to assign it to a variable.

Comment: neg_score = result['neg_score']

Comment: as typically you would be returning multiple columns you need some way to index into them.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped :)